# Setting Environment Variables For NMAKE Before Building A 'Makefile Solution'

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I have an MSVC [Makefile Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txcwa2xx(VS.80).aspx) in which I need to set an environment variable before running NMAKE.  For x64 builds I needs to set it to one value, and for x86 builds I need to set it to something else.

So for example, when doing a build I would want to `SET PLATFORM=win64` if I'm building a 64-bit compile, or `SET PLATFORM=win32` if I'm building 32-bit.

There does not appear to be an option to set environment variables or add a pre-build even for makefile projects.

How do I do this?

EDIT: Running MSVC 2008

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just edit the Configuration Properties + NMake + Build Command Line.  Click the button with the dots and enter something like this:

```
set PLATFORM=win32
nmake -f makefile.mak
```

Repeat for your 64-bit configuration.